# How to pass a named parameter to an Visual FoxPro OLE DB Command?

Tags: .net, oledb, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I recently accessed some DBF in VS.NET, using Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider. Everything worked fine until I found that I could not figure out how to pass a parameter to the query.
I used this as query

```
Select `group`, `i_name`, `j_name`, ... From `mytable` Where `valid` AND `group` IN (@`group1`, @`group2`);
```

And added two parameters named `group1` and `group2`, with string values, to the parameter collection (ie. `IDbCommand.Parameters`).

Then I received an OleDbException, telling me Syntax error.

I've tried this

```
Select `group`, `i_name`, `j_name`, ... From `mytable` Where `valid` AND `group` IN (?, ?);
```

And it worked.

I just wonder if the FoxPro OLE DB Provider supports the named parameters? If so, how to reference it in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FoxPro OLE DB Provider does not support named parameters.  I found this to be a problem for some stuff that I worked on so I ended up created a wrapper around the FoxPro OLE DB Provider.  Here is an [example](http://randomdevnotes.com/2013/06/02/using-named-parameters-when-accessing-visual-foxpro-data-from-net/) using named parameters with my provider if you are interested.

Comment: So I can be sure it's a problem of the provider itself now. Thanks a lot!