# Oledbcommand with date in the where clause

Tags: oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am using oledbconnection to read dbf files. I am trying to search all data from a specific dbf database. I am doing it well when there is no date in where clause. But when I am using date as a where I am having zero result.

String constr = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(cashierPath).FullName + 
                ";Exclusive=false;Nulls=false";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
        OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {


            cmd.CommandText = "select id from " + Path.GetFileName(cashierPath) + " where todate=@todate";
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
           {
               new OleDbParameter("@todate", "2016-07-21")


           });
            using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    String data = reader.GetString(0);
                    MessageBox.Show(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't really know what the problem.

Comment: The Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider does not support named parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602133/how-to-pass-a-named-parameter-to-an-visual-foxpro-ole-db-command

Comment: I see, Thanks for the help